# Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space. If $S,T∈L(V,V)$ prove that $ST$ and $TS$ have the same eigenvalues whenever $T$ is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

I know the result is
true even when T is not an isomorphism but how would I show it if it was one, however.

Comment: They have the same characteristic polynomial, they have the same eigenvalues. Perhaps you should try that.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\lambda I-TS=T(\lambda I-ST)T^{-1}.$$

Can you take it from here ?